# jQuery selector DOM traversal direction and efficiency

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance, dom-traversal

What is the standard direction of search for multipart `jQuery` selectors?

e.g. the case

```
$('#myTable tr.selected');
```

Is the first search for `#myTable` and then the `tr.selected` search is only within that table?

Or is the first search for all `tr.selected` on the page and the second search checking each ones parent nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You should watch [this talk by John Resig on the subject](http://ejohn.org/blog/the-dom-is-a-mess/). He says that, contrary to what you might expect, selector engines will search for `tr.selected` and then see if an ancestor matches `#myTable`.

Comment: this is the way css works i believe, which is what lead me to ask the question. This would suggest that in general, the less information you provide to a selector the more efficient it will be.

Comment: I don't know for sure. Since jQuery uses Sizzle, and Sizzle uses `querySelectorAll` if it's available, the answer may be "it depends". Different browsers may do things differently and may have different optimizations. Unless there's some standard specifying exactly how a user agent should traverse the DOM when using `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I think your comment above is right. In the video *(I haven't watched it yet, but thanks for posting it)*, John must be talking about comparisons between competing javascript based selector engines. Is that right?

Comment: He does mention that stuff a bit, but the details are a little fuzzy to be honest - it's been a while since I watched it :)

Answer (score 1):

> The first search for **#myTable** and then the **tr.selected** search is only within that table

First it looks for an element with the id of `myTable` and then finds descendants that are 'tr' tags with the `selected` class